# Calling name of the numbers automatically in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, numbers

I have an ini file with information like:

```
slExpsave_0 = 0.23;
slExpsave_1 = 0.40;
slExpsave_2 = -0.85;
```

...

I need to use them in a loop;

...

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    slExpArray[i].value = slExpsave_[i];
}
```

But it doesn't work.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please add a tag for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is Javascript, so you should use an array if you want to access them within a loop:

```
slExpsave_ = [0.23, 0.40, -0.85];
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain my problem more clearly.

As I did it manually, It worked as I wanted:

```
slExpsave_0 = 0.23;
slExpsave_1 = 0.40;
slExpsave_2 = -0.85;

slExpArray[0].value = slExpsave_0; // output is 0.23;
slExpArray[1].value = slExpsave_1; // output is 0.40;
slExpArray[2].value = slExpsave_2; // output is -0.85;
```

when I tried to do it automatically by put in the for loop:

the first one I tried:

```
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        slExpArray[i].value = "slExpsave_" + i;
    }
// output  is slExpsave_0, slExpsave_1, slExpsave_2

the second was:



for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            slExpArray[i].value = slExpsave_[i];
        }
    // doesn't work.
```